# GAS: How to make the `submit` button be shown in a checkbox with a big list of items?

Tags: google-apps-script

I build this script that, after iterates over the files of a folder, creates a UI that shows the files as a checkbox list:

```
function showList(folderID) {
  var folder = DocsList.getFolderById(folderID);
  var files = folder.getFiles();  
  arrayList = [];
  for (var file in files) {
    Logger.log("file = " + file);
    file = files[file];
    var fileName = file.getName();
    var fileId = file.getId();
    var newArray = [fileName, "some info", fileId];
    arrayList.push(newArray);
  }   
    var mydoc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var app = UiApp.createApplication();
    var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('panel'); 
    panel.add(app.createHidden('checkbox_total', arrayList.length));
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++){
      var checkbox = app.createCheckBox().setName('checkbox_isChecked_'+i).setText(arrayList[i][0]);
      panel.add(checkbox);
    }
    var handler = app.createServerHandler('submit').addCallbackElement(panel);
    panel.add(app.createButton('Submit', handler));
    app.add(panel);
    mydoc.show(app);
}
```

My problem: the number of files is big and the `submit` button of the panel isn't being shown. How to deal with this? How to adding a scrollbar make the `submit` button be shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that was easy. Digging the documentation I solve that. You just build a scroll panel and add your previous panel to it:

```
   var scroll = app.createScrollPanel().setPixelSize(800, 800);
   scroll.add(panel);
   app.add(scroll);

 //   app.add(panel);
    mydoc.show(app);
```